# "something went wrong during" OneNote sync

Tags: microsoft-onenote, onedrive

I have a OneNote notebook which I access from several machines (all Win8, not RT) running either OneNote 2013 (for the desktop and laptop machine) or OneNote 2010 (for the slate). I believe the notebook syncs to my SkyDrive account, which has 70.1 of 125GB free.

However they have stopped successfully syncing, throwing the error

`We're sorry, something went wrong during sync. We'll try again later. (Error code: 0xE000005E)`

The `Get Help` button leads to http://office.microsoft.com/en-GB/onenote-help/troubleshoot-synchronization-errors-in-onenote-2010-HA102774369.aspx?ver=15&app=onenote.exe which does not include that error number.

How do I diagnose, or even better fix, whatever is going wrong?

========== EDIT ==========

Following suggestions in the comments below I have tried a second, new, OneNote notebook. This one is also created in OneNote 2010.

When I first created the new notebook I got the error:

`OneNote cannot sync changes in this notebook because WebDAV support is not enabled on your computer. (Error code: 0xE0000784)`

Then I enabled WebDAV and now I get the following error for the new notebook:

`An error occurred while attempting to sync this section or notebook. (Error code: 0xE000106C)`

So the new notebook also cannot sync, but with a different error code.

Comment: Have you tried a different notebook?  I suspect this is a Onenote 2013 vs oneNote 2010 compatability conflict.  Furthermore you only believe it syncs to your SkyDrive?

Comment: I cannot see it listed on my SkyDrive, but the URL to open it in a browser looks like my SkyDrive. I'll try a different notebook, though if that works I'm not sure what I'll have proved. Should I just abandon the one that's failing and start afresh?

Comment: Just verify the problem surfaces with a new notebook

Comment: A different problem surfaces with a new notebook. I've edited the question with the additional information.

Comment: This sounds like a bug with compatability between OneNote 2013 and OneNote 2010

Comment: That sounds plausible but I do hope not, there's one 2010 feature I'm loathed to give up.

Comment: So report the problem to Microsoft.

Comment: OR: Web integration has been diabled through Group Policy by your administrator?
Refer to [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fd10f9a8-021b-463f-b877-1d89ed584a37/onenote-2010-how-to-disable-the-skydrive-integration-via-group-policy?forum=officeitproprevious)

Answer (score 3):

I've come across this before myself and the solution for me at the time was to go into Services (run "services.msc") and make sure the WebClient service is started.

[image: Windows Services window]

Comment: Thank you! I've given up OneNote for 1 year because of this issue. I can finally get back to it :)